# If a client is someone we sell to, what do we call those we buy from?

Tags: single-word-requests

We say *client list* or *customers* for people we offer our goods or services, but what word should I use for the company I buy the goods from?

Is that also a client?

Comment: You are their client, but they are your *vendor*.

Comment: They are your supplier.

Comment: You should call them "Sir" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess 'vendor' defined by google as

> A person or company offering something for sale, esp. a trader in the
>   street: "an Italian ice cream vendor".

Definition of vendor from oxforddictionaries.com

> noun a person or company
>   offering something for sale, especially a trader in the street: an
>   Italian ice-cream vendor /also ˈvɛndɔː/ Law the seller in a sale,
>   especially of property.

Comment: Can we call company - a vendor?'

Comment: I think so! I have heard lot of people use those terms especially in the job market. I have heard sentences like "The consultancy company is going to setup my interviews with vendors"

Comment: I disagree with this answer. In the context of a company, it doesn't normally buy from "vendors". If the company *has* vendors, it actually "sells" to them.

Comment: how about a company trying to employ contractors/part-time workers from a placement agency? won't one play the role of a vendor and the other the role of a buyer? even though both are companies.

Comment: @camelbrush: Obviously *every* commercial company has "customers" they sell to, and almost every company buys stuff. I'm simply saying that in practice, if someone speaking from the company's perspective refers to "our vendors", that will almost always mean *our authorised distributors, who sell our products/services to customers we don't deal with directly*.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers
agreed.

Answer (score 4):

As @GEdgar says if you buy goods in order to sell them on (regardless of whether you do anything to enhance them or not), you *get* them from your ***suppliers***.

You'd only normally refer to your company's *vendors* if you don't actually sell direct to end-users. Check a few instances of [our vendors have](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22return%20to%20the%20well%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22our%20vendors%20have%22&oq=%22our%20vendors%20have%22&gs_l=serp.3...3659533.3659533.14.3660121.1.1.0.0.0.0.49.49.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.2.serp.zC6VwOwO4rs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k&fp=d5d2e43114717f23&biw=1233&bih=875) in Google Books, where they're invariably referring to *people who buy our product in [large] wholesale quantities, and sell it on [in smaller amounts] to many more people*.